# Reading textfile skipping bunch of lines then proceeding to other lines

Tags: c#, linq, streamreader

I want to skip lines that i will read in the text file, as you can see below the line 0, line 1 and line 2 is skip (first three lines of text file) then it follows a read this (3 read this) then next is (4 skip this)

this is the the pattern:

(first 3 lines of text file is skipped then followed by 
(3) read this then 
(4) skip
 this till the end of text file) rinse and repeat for other text files, i need help with this kind of pattern.

```
Line 0 - Skip This
Line 1 - Skip This
Line 2 - Skip This
Line 3 - Read This
Line 4 - Read This
Line 5 - Read This
Line 6 - Skip This
Line 7 - Skip This
Line 8 - Skip This
Line 9 - Skip This
Line 10 - Read This
Line 11 - Read This
Line 12- Read This
Line 13 - Skip This
Line 14 - Skip This
Line 15- Skip This
Line 16- Skip This
Line 17 - Read This and so on
```

Code that i tried.

```
string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f.File);
foreach (string line in Lines.Skip(3))
{
   try
   {
      string[] readLineSplit = line.Split('|');

      if (readLineSplit.Length > 1)
      {
         var id = readLineSplit[0].ToString();
         var flagvalue = readLineSplit[1].ToString();
         var status = readLineSplit[2].ToString();
         Lines.Skip(4).ToString();
         Console.WriteLine("ID {0}, Value {1}, Status {2}", id, flagvalue, status)
      }    
   }
   catch (FileNotFoundException error)
   {   
      Console.WriteLine(error);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? All you have given us is a problem.

Comment: i want to know how i can do this with linq or streamreader.

Comment: You've already identified the `StreamReader` class as the one to use. Have a look through its methods and you will immediately see one that is applicable to your situation.

Comment: The show that you've made some effort. So far this is just "I need to do something, tell me how." SO isn't a personal code writing service.

Comment: i will update my post on what i have tried, sorry forgot that.

Comment: yes i did not include the mysql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than reading in all the lines and then attempting to extract the ones that you need, you can instead just read the lines that you want without storing the unneeded ones in memory:

```
var lines = new List<string>();
var counter = 0;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename)) {
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
        //ignore the first 3 lines
        if (counter >= 3) {
            //now work out where in the pattern of 7 (3 read, 4 skip) we are
            var mod = (counter - 3) % 7;
            //if the first 3 of the 7, keep it
            if (mod < 3)
                lines.Add(line);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That reads 1 line and exits, not doing anything because counter is less than 3. It doesn't loop

Comment: @JamesBarrass Thanks - got hung up on the inner logic and completely missed that bit :)

Comment: Can you post real data.  I've been parsing text files for over 40 years and have lots of experience.  Using module technique isn't very robust especially if the code has blank lines and page feeds.

Comment: @jdweng The OP specifically said "lines" - if there's a larger requirement, he should post it, but bearing in mind that if it gets too big, the question is likely to be closed as Too Broad.

Comment: thanks @JamesThorpe the first 3 lines is omited but it doesn't follow the pattern after that read (3) then skip (4) i don't know why, i can still see the values that should be removed.

Comment: @jdweng the data comes from a laboratory instrument machine, i can post it if you want.

Comment: @KevinRodriguez Are you sure?  [It works fine for me on your given input](http://imgur.com/D3zuiav)

Comment: I would like to see actual data.  I think there is additional parsing that is needed that can be done in one step rather than two steps.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, there probably is - but this question was about reading and skipping lines, not the parsing of the lines that need to be parsed.

Comment: Why give a incomplete solution when you can do it right.  Who cares what the question asked.  I have a lot more insight with parsing files than the person who asked the question.

Comment: @JamesThorpe it works just fine, but the pattern breaks for some reason, screen shot here http://i.imgur.com/WdEL1UU.jpg?1 it breaks at line 2P and 1P

Comment: @jdweng Because the question was specifically about reading and skipping the lines.  There's nothing in the question other than the attempted code at what needs to be parsed.  If that was part of the question, and it didn't then fall under the Too Broad category, it would be part of my answer.

Comment: @KevinRodriguez Are you sure that those lines definitely fall into the defined pattern?

Comment: @JamesThorpe i figured what the culprit is http://i.imgur.com/nkSNWaF.jpg the  " | " before 2P, i forgot about that :( captured from text file.

Comment: So if you can't rely on a fixed 3/4 pattern, then I agree with @jdweng and you'll need to find whatever rules do match for each line that you need, and parse them out that way, but that becomes a somewhat different question.

Comment: It looks like the data is coming from a serial device event.  Events do not always get a full line of data at one time.  You have to join lines.  Normally I recommend sending a return character in the device software so the receiver can properly parse the lines.

Comment: You need to take a good college level course on Communication Theory to fully understand devices.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f.File);
for (int i = 3; i < Lines.Length-3; i += 7)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
    string[] readLineSplit = Line [i+j].Split('|');
    etc..
  }
}
```

Comment: You need something to fill like a `List<string>` or better a `List<SomeClass>`, however +1

Comment: simple, effective, down to earth coding

Answer (score 3):

This would be a short LINQ solution:

```
var result = Lines.Skip(3).Where((val,idx)=>idx%7<3).Select((x)=>x);
```

`Lines` could be an array of all lines of the file or simply `File.ReadLines(filename)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off with the stream reader, but for a Linq, Skip/Take answer try

```
        List<string> lines = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();

        IEnumerable<string> group;
        int c = 0;
        do
        {
            group = lines.Skip(3+7*c).Take(3);
            foreach (var s in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            c++;
        } while (group.Count() == 3);
```